# React - dynamic scheduler bug - rendering empty <td /> outside of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

i am creating scheduler app and i wanted to do scheduler with events, where user can click on event and register. Everything works fine, but somehow if i have got rowSpan={2} inside daysOfWeek map function, it keeps rendering empty cell component outside of table for each rowSpan that is larger than 1.. I tried multiple resources and tricks, but i could not fix the problem

Here is current picture how it looks for more info
[image]

code:

```
  <div className="overflow-x-auto pb-5">
      <table className="w-full border-separate">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            {daysOfWeek.map((day, index) => {
              const dayDate = getDateForDay(currentWeekView.startOfWeek, index);
              return (
                <th
                  className={classNames(cellSize, isToday(dayDate) && 'text-primary-blue-dark')}
                  key={day}
                >
                  <p className="flex flex-col">
                    {day}
                    <span className="font-medium">{dayDate.format('D.M')}</span>
                  </p>
                </th>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {scheduleHours.map((hour) => {
            return (
              <tr key={hour}>
                <td className="p-4 ">{hour}</td>
                {daysOfWeek.map((day, index) => {
                  const reservations = data?.filter(
                    (r) =>
                      formatToCurrentDay(r.starts_at) === day &&
                      moment(r.starts_at).hour() === hour,
                  );

                  if (reservations?.length) {
                    const maxDuration = Math.max(
                      ...reservations.map((reservation) =>
                        moment(reservation.ends_at).diff(moment(reservation.starts_at), 'hours'),
                      ),
                    );

                    return (
                      <td rowSpan={maxDuration}>
                        <div className="flex gap-1">
                          {reservations.map((reservation) => {
                            const classInfo = classes_data.find(
                              (cl) => cl.class_id === reservation.class_id,
                            )!;

                            return (
                              classInfo && (
                                <ReservationCell
                                  key={reservation.reservation_id}
                                  classes_data={classInfo}
                                  reservation_data={reservation}
                                  userId={userId}
                                />
                              )
                            );
                          })}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return <EmptyCell day={day} key={`${day}-${hour}`} isDayToday={false} />;
                  }
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I want to achieve to have multiple events at same time, what i have done, but if events is for 2 hours, it should display correctly from 17-19h for example and dont create EmptyCells (td element) outside of table.